# Use Function Key + Page Up/ Page Down as Volume Control

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to use the function key and page up/page down to control the volume on my laptop. There is a touch panel at the top that controls it, but it has worn out a bit and isn't responsive. How do I configure this?

I own a Dell Inspiron 1525 (with Win7Pro)

Thanks

**Answer**: Using AutoHotKey, here is the script I wrote (with Windows key)

```
#PgUp::Send {Volume_Up 3}
#PgDn::Send {Volume_Down 3}
```

Comment: Laptop function key behavior is very closely tied to the manufacturer of the laptop. Please provide more information about the make and model of the specific laptop.

Comment: +1 for eleven81's Autohotkey solution. You might like volumouse. http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html . It uses the scroll pad and a modifier to change volume. Doesn't accept the fn key you want, but any other modifier+scroll or WIN+ARROW. Works great on my 1525.

Comment: To provide an example why Doug Harris's question is relevant: I tried using the FN key on my laptop but the OS never got any events when pressing the key (`key down` events), only when releasing it (`key up` events) which made the thing rather useless for almost anything, especially modifier-like. I guess it was almost completely handled by hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

There is [some information](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic298.html) about [special keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) like your (unspecified) laptop's Fn key.

Comment: I ended up using my Windows Key instead. Thanks